# AWS S3 bucket policy public read, restricted write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up a policy to my brand new, nice bucket called files.mybucket.com that states:

1. Everyone can read my objects
2. Only some IAM users can do everything else.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "getAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com",
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "writeSome",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/John",
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/Dave"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com",
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

The above seems to have no effect: even if I remove "John" principal from the statement I still can upload things with it through the console and Cloudberry Explorer.

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "getAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com",
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "writeSome",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/John",
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/Dave"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com",
            "arn:aws:s3:::files.mybucket.com/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

This one looks promising as it keeps users from writing (if I remove John, I can't write with it anymore) BUT it also blocks get requests from unauthenticated people (and I want them to be able to see the content).

So, the question: how to allow people to get my files AND keep everybody except John And Dave from writing on the bucket?

It's driving me nuts. I appreciate the help.

Comment: So the second policy doesn't work?

Comment: No, it blocks write requests correctly but it also keeps people from reading. I'm using it to store images for a site and get Access Denied when I try to show the images there.

Comment: I see. You use `s3:*` which denies everything to everyone except John and Dave. **Deny always wins**. But be **careful** with `NonPrinciple`. AWS recommends [NOT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html) using it unless you absolutely must.

Comment: Good to know that the denials win! But I still don't get it: if I don't use NotPrincipal, it seems the only way is to create a "deny" to "*" with every action except GetObject, but that would take precedence over every "allow" to the Principals in another statements, right? I don't see a solution that doesn't involve NotPrincipal for this case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule:

- Rules that apply to *everybody* should go in the **Bucket Policy**
- Rule that only apply to specific users should be applied to the **IAM Users**, or an **IAM Group** of users

Therefore:

- Create a **bucket policy** to grant Read access to everyone (the first part of your policy, above)
- For every user who should be allowed to access the bucket, add a policy to their **IAM User**

This avoids the need for `Deny` policies, which always cause problems.

Comment: That's it! Thank you vey much.